# Cython: use pyximport in Win7 64 bit with MSVC

Tags: python, cython

In this [wiki](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows) it very clearly explained that we need to run the following command to use `distutils` to use Cython in Win 64 bits:

```
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
setenv /x64 /release
```

This works with the setup.py method perfectly. However, I was wondering whether there is a way to use `pyximport` as well. I tried to run this in Python before I import pyximport, but it didn't work:

```
import sys
import os
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    os.system('set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1')
    os.system('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd /x64 /release')
```

Any ideas?